# How can I disable the "toggle Wi-Fi" key combination on my Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, keyboard, fn-key

I rarely need to disable the wireless network on my laptop, so the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> key combination is usually just in the way. It's even more frustrating for some of my friends and family, who don't know the key combination to begin with and so can't get their wireless to work when they accidentally disable it.

**Is there a universal way to disable the "toggle Wi-Fi" key combination on Windows 7 computers?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Fn+F12 is not windows-7 specific. Fn+F12 sleeps my computer according to my keyboard sticker.

You should install all the software of your laptop. Those software will allow you to customize the shortcuts, enable/disable them hopefully.

Same goes for desktop keyboards, the correct way to change how a key behaves is using its own software.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tolga Hoşgör explained in his (her?) answer, this functionality is not OS-specific, so no, there's no universal way. If you're lucky, the manufacturer of your laptop provides a program that you can use to customise and disable the Fn-shortcuts (wifi toggle, brightness controls, and so on). In most cases, however, these shortcut keys are handled directly by the BIOS and the OS never even sees them, so unless your laptop's BIOS provides an option to turn them off, you're probably out of luck.

I must say, though, that hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> (or any other function key) at the same time by accident seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: It's not unlikely if it's right next to the Mute button (Fn + F11), which I use often. Even if it were, that would just make it all the more difficult to find out what's wrong when you actually do press it by mistake.